# Xcode Framework wrapper for Library ( Exposing library headers)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries

```
MyProject
    MyFramework
            MyLibrary.h
            libMyLibrary.a
```

I'm creating a Framework wrapper round a static library. The header (MyLibrary.h) needs to be accessable from the ViewController.m file in MyProject

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@import MyFramework;

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[[MyLibrary alloc]init]test];
}
```

[image]
I have set MyLibrary.h to public

MyFramework.h contains the line `#import <MyFramework/MyLibrary.h>`

'Embedded Binaries' is set to MyFramework

When I run the above code I get...

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyLibrary", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

The only way I have found to solve this problem is to create a private Class in MyFramework (called TestClass) and allocate MyLibrary. I assume this forces MyLibrary to be linked at runtime and accessable from ViewController.
But this is ugly as hell, what am I missing?

```
#import "TestClass.h"
#import "MyLibrary.h"

@implementation TestClass
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {

        [MyLibrary alloc]; //solves the problem of MyLibrary being accessable from  ViewController
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: You need to add `#import "MyFramework.h"` instead of `@import` in your `ViewController.m` class.

Comment: Thanks, just tried that and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by adding -ObjC to Other Linker Flags